# Trim leading whitespace from links

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, editor, usability

There's a lot of posts with the pattern `http://%20http` ([here's](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2f%2520%22) an example search for Stack Overflow; the Stack Exchange multi-site search unfortunately does not grok this syntax) and by quick testing, I was able to repro by clicking the "insert link" icon in the post editor and pasting a URL with a space in front.

[image: Screen shot of editor]

I can see no useful scenario where links would need to have whitespace at either the beginning or the end, and this causes rather inexplicable broken links in posts.  Could the editor please be fixed to trim leading and trailing whitespace before inserting the pasted address?